# Is device memory allocated using CudaMalloc inaccessible on the device with free?

Tags: memory, dynamic, cuda

I cannot deallocate memory on the host that I've allocated on the device or deallocate memory on the device that I allocated on the host.  I'm using CUDA 5.5 with VS2012 and Nsight.  Is it because the heap that's on the host is not transferred to the heap that's on the device or the other way around, so dynamic allocations are unknown between host and device?

If this is in the documentation, it is not easy to find.  It's also important to note, an error wasn't thrown until I ran the program with CUDA debugging and with Memory Checker enabled.  The problem did not cause a crash outside of CUDA debugging, but would've cause problems later if I hadn't checked for memory issues retroactively.  If there's a handy way to copy the heap/stack from host to device, that'd be fantastic... hopes and dreams.

Here's an example for my question:

```
__global__ void kernel(char *ptr)
{
  free(ptr);
}

void main(void)
{
  char *ptr;
  cudaMalloc((void **)&ptr, sizeof(char *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  kernel<<<1, 1>>>(ptr);
}
```

Comment: I've created deep copy functions for complex dynamic structures that work. I was hoping to avoid data replication on the device to provide restructuring flexibility--but, I kind of expected to have to load the entire data set somewhere on the device and having to have a separate format that's less condensed. This is the perfect spot for a design decision. This limitation really just keeps me from performing any initial restructuring on the host before the object(s) are transferred to the device. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't do this.

This topic is specifically covered in the programming guide [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#interoperability-host-memory-api)

> Memory allocated via malloc() cannot be freed using the runtime (i.e., by calling any of the free memory functions from Device Memory). 
>   Similarly, memory allocated via the runtime (i.e., by calling any of the memory allocation functions from Device Memory) cannot be freed via free().

It's in section B.18.2 of the programming guide,  within section B.18 "B.18. Dynamic Global Memory Allocation and Operations".

The basic reason for it is that the mechanism used to reserve allocations using the runtime (e.g. `cudaMalloc`, `cudaFree`) is separate from the device code allocator, and in fact they reserve out of logically separate regions of global memory.

You may want to read the entire B.18 section of the programming guide, which covers these topics on device dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: It also seems malloc on the device causes host-based cudaMemcpy to throw an "unknown error."  Does the host API require memory to be on the heap to manage at all?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Both cases are not allowed, and are referred to in the area I excerpted in gray above.  Your use of `heap` here might be a bit casual.  The *system heap* is managed by system API calls like `malloc`.  The *device heap* is managed by device API calls like (device) `malloc`.  The cuda runtime API calls are separate from the above 2 APIs, and `cudaMalloc` does not remove memory either from the system heap or the device heap.  As I mentioned, the memory areas are logically separate.

Comment: To elaborate the process 1) host:cudaMalloc a struct object which encapsulates pointers, 2) host:cudaMemcpy that struct from host to device memory, 3) device:malloc the encapsulated pointers in the struct object, 4) host:cudaMemcpy that struct object from device to host memory, 5) host:malloc temporary host memory locations, 6) host:cudaMemcpy the device memory pointed to by the encapsulated pointers to the temporary host memory locations, 7) set the host struct object pointers to the host memory, and 8) host:cudaFree the device memory. Steps 3&6, device:malloc & host:cudaMemcpy aren't jiving.

Comment: You cannot do step 6.   A pointer created by device malloc cannot be used in the runtime API in any way, shape, or form.  The two API's are not interoperable, the two regions are logically separate, and you cannot mix the two.   Pointers pointing to the device heap, and any memory they reference, are completely invisible to the host API.  If you pass a device heap pointer to the host API, you will get an error.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I didn't understand.  memcpy doesn't work that way, it doesn't utilize the allocation heap unless using debug mode in VS2012... so one could take advantage of no checks to grab the memory you know is there.  But, if the CUDA API always acts like the CRT debug versions of the memory functions, I'll have to find another way.  Was really hoping not to move data back and forth between host and device to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to mixing dynamic memory allocation on the host using CRT, with the host's CUDA API, and with the kernel memory functions.  First off, as mentioned above, they all must be managed separately using strategy that does not require dynamic allocations to be transferred directly between system and device without prior communication and coordination.  Manual data copies are required that do not validate against the kernel's *device heap* as noted in Robert's answer/comments.

I also suggest to keep track of, *audit*, the number of bytes allocated and deallocated in the 3 different memory management APIs.  For instance, every time a system:malloc, host:cudaMalloc, device:malloc or associated frees are called, use a variable to hold the number of bytes allocated or deallocated in each heap, i.e. from system, host, device.  This helps with tracking leaks when debugging.

> The process is complex to dynamically allocate, manage, and audit
>   memory between the system, host and device perspectives for deep
>   dynamic structure copies.  Here is a strategy that works, suggestions
>   are welcomed:
>
> 1. Allocate system memory using **cudaHostMalloc** or **malloc** of a
>      structural type that contains pointers on the *system heap*;
> 2. Allocate device memory from host for the struct, and copy the
>      structure to the device (i.e. **cudaMalloc**, **cudaMemcpy**, etc.);
> 3. From within a kernel, use **malloc** to create a memory allocation
>      managed using the *device heap* and save the pointer(s) in the
>      structure that exists on the device from step 2;
> 4. Communicate what was allocated by the kernel to system by exchanging
>      the size of the allocations for each of the pointers in the struct;
> 5. Host performs the same allocation on the device using CUDA API (i.e.
>      **cudaMalloc**) from the system as was done by the kernel on the device,
>      recommended to have a separate pointer variable in the structure for
>      this;
> 6. At this point, the memory allocated dynamically from the kernel in
>      device memory can be manually copied to the location dynamically
>      allocated by the host in device memory (i.e. not using host:**memcpy**,
>      device:**memcpy** or **cudaMemcpy**);
> 7. Kernel cleans up memory allocations; and,
> 8. Host uses **cudaMemcpy** to move the structure from the device, a
>      similar strategy outlined in the above answer's comment can be used
>      as necessary for deep copies.

Note, **cudaHostMalloc** and system:**malloc** (or **cudaHostMalloc**) both share the same system heap, making *system heap* and *host heap* the same and interoperable, as mentioned in the CUDA guide, referenced above.  Therefore, only *system heap* and *device heap* are mentioned.

Comment: If you use cudaMalloc(), be ready to provide a host pointer to the allocated memory in order to call cudaFree() upon it, regardless how deep your list (or whatever structure) goes. Yes, it requires additional resources. But it's exactly what has to be done. Period.